# Errors attempting to push to Bitbucket using ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Using https I'm able to push a local repo to my Bitbucket repo with no problem.  But for some reason ssh with git is not working - even though my ssh keys seem to be working otherwise.

Here's the https that works:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://<myName>@bitbucket.org/<myName>/<myRepo>.git (fetch)
origin  https://<myName>@bitbucket.org/<myName>/<myRepo>.git (push)
```

Here's the origin url that doesn't work: (EDITED: to make clear that set-url WAS used.)

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:<myName>/<myRepo>.git
$ git remote -v 
...
origin  git@bitbucket.org:<myName>/<myRepo>.git (push)
```

It produces the dreaded error:

```
$ git push -u origin --all
...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: logg
```

I realize that "logg" is the beginning of a longer error message.  In an attempt to read that message I've tried:

```
$ ssh git@bitbucket.org git-receive-pack <myName>/<myRepo>
```

But this locks up after a message that doesn't seem to help:

```
<a long hex string> refs/heads/masterreport-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.10.5
0000
```

After hitting the enter key four times it finally returns:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:
```

(Yes, that didn't specify the character.)

My ssh passkey seemed to be working, but just to confirm I tried:

```
$ ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org
```

This returned a long reply.  Near the end was included:

```
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

Without any more success, I've tried several variations on my origin url, including:

```
...
origin  ssh:git@bitbucket.org:<myName>/<myRepo>.git (push)
```

Which resulted in:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Is all of this clear?  Shouldn't ssh work here?  What else can I try?

Comment: Not clear. If you have cloned using git clone https url then git push will also use https connection. If you want to change from https to SSH then you have to set the url. Refer this - https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud SSH connection is down: https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/jbvzjz4yldss — now resolved. Try again.

Comment: @rootkonda:  yes set-url was used to change the origin url.  The question has been edited to (hopefully) make this more clear.

Comment: @phd:  that was interesting news, but ssh is still not working from this end.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative URL would have been `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<myName>/<myRepo>.git` (not `ssh:git...`)

And the [incident mentioned in the comments](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/jbvzjz4yldss) remains the most likely explanation.

I just tested an SSH URL (with `git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:<myName>/<myRepo>.git`) and it does work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that proper url format.  It does seem to get over the "Could not resolve hostname" error.  But the "bad line length character: logg" error still comes up.  Thanks also for pointing out the ls-remote test.  This does work for me also.  So I must still be doing something wrong.  'Will keep researching...

Comment: @PatrickReagan bad line lenght points to a .bashrc which is not silent (add logs on stdout/stderr)